# What Generates This Error 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation'?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 APP and I have created a popup element on Page Launch and use as a static variable popup.

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
     RemoveCurrentDeactivationSettings();

     APPCommon.popupsetup();
}

//APPCOMMON Page
public static Popup busyindicator;
public static void popupsetup()
{
    busyindicator = new Popup()
    {
        Child = new Border()
        {
            Child = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadBusyIndicator()
            {
                FontSize = 25,
                IsRunning = true,
                IsEnabled = true,
                Content = "Processing...",
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
            },
            Opacity = 0.8,
            Name = "busyindicate",
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth,
            Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight
        }
    };
}
```

It works fine most of the time even when it is in heavy modes too. However, I get an error on rare occasion when the app enters IDLE Mode (Lock Screen or Start Menu) when I get back to the app from start menu instead of using Back Key I get an error saying '**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**' on the following line which is in my `DefaultPage`.

Exception In Detail '**Element is already the child of another element.**'

```
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     App.RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
     this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(APPCommon.busyindicator); // Error Occurs
}
```

Therefore, I would like to know why this is happening and what I Should do to solve this.

Comment: Did you check the exception?  You know, it has lots of information, probably information about why the exception was thrown.  That's why exceptions get thrown, you know.

Comment: Element is already the child of another element.

Comment: Do you show the Popup in other views in your app?

Comment: yeah i use it like a common function like message box... it's built in launching page and the store in a static variable. then add to layoutroot when the page is moved to another and remove when the user is leaving the page...!

Comment: There you go.  It's already added to another parent.  Possibly the current one.  See if it is already added.  And, if not, refactor your code so you create a new instance of it every time.  Poof.  Error gone.

Comment: Yeah but layout-root is different page to page, isn't it? isn't page layout-root is replaced by current layout root?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a "factory" method instead of a shared instance of the Popup.  To use a global static UI element is begging for trouble ...

```
public static Popup CreatePopup()
{
    return new Popup
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

And:

```
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(APPCommon.CreatePopup());
}
```

Comment: Actually i was trying to use one element for all the ui but will this be a problem to the memory performance... cause i am trying to squeeze every thing to get the perfect result and it's hard to work windows mobile application when the os cannot handle those ui on idle mode....!

Comment: @gayan1991 I was thinking that maybe you had memory in mind.  But I don't think the singleton approach really gains you anything -- just causes an exception to be thrown whenever the Popup might be used in 2 places at once.

Comment: Well i am not sure how much of a gain that i'm getting but i'm developing a CRM app for a client in lowest costing device like NOKIA LUMIA 520 which has 414 MB in overall. I will try this and let you know how this change would affect.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    App.RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
    this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(APPCommon.busyindicator);
}
```

Comment: Actualy it does not work. it still shows and in detail it is 'Element is already the child of another element.'